# I can't Move attributes in Magento - Catalog - Attibutes - Manage Attributes 1.9.2.4

Tags: product-attribute, ce-1.9.2.4

I can't move the attributes in magento to unassigned attribute 
anyone knows the solution ?

[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshots

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar hello thak you for your answer i have take one , but when i like to move it gives me forbidden sign for move ..

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to move from left to right. Which attributes did you tried?

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar short description , i want disable  from product view  . thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove system attribute from attribute set. Short description is a system attribute and you cannot remove it.

However, you can hide those from frontend by editing ../catalog/product/view.phtml file and comment out short description code there.

Comment: thanks what i have write in the code ?

Comment: sorry, didnt get you.

Comment: im new , how i hide and wich line ?

Comment: are you using any theme?

Comment: yes , sorry for late answer y internet was not going in the lat 24 hours

Comment: just go to catalog/product/view.phtml file residing in app/design your theme folder..